# how to decrease the amount of subscribe operators and replace with a different rxjs operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

Trying to **decrease** the numbers of **subscribes** and use the equivalent **flatMap\switchMap\do\tap** **rxjs** operators for the mentioned below code.
It is working, but I'm aware that this is not the best way of doing it.
The code act as follow:
First - there is a credential check (usename and pass):
A. if it fetch a user data, it resetLoginAttempts - reset number of login attempts to 0 and routes to a different route.
B. If not (A) - it increaseLoginAttempts - increase the number of login attempts by 1. The service fetch back the number of login after the increment. According to that it check - if the login attempts >= 3 then it generateCaptcha, which also return observable.

```
//loginSrv.Login - return observable of userData (json)
//sessionService.resetLoginAttempts - return observable of void 
//sessionService.increaseLoginAttempts - return observable of any (json)
//loginSrv.GetCaptcha - return observable of any (svg image)

subscriptions : Subscription[] = [];
login()
{
  this.subscriptions.push(this.loginSrv.Login(userName, password).subscribe(result =>
  {
    if (result &&  result.userData)
    {
      this.sessionService.resetLoginAttempts().subscribe();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('');
    }
    else
    {
        this.subscriptions.push(this.sessionService.increaseLoginAttempts().subscribe(result => 
        {
          if (result.loginAttempts >= 3)
          {
            this.generateCaptcha();
          }
        }, error => 
          {
                throwError(error))
          }
      ));
    }
  }, (error => throwError(error))
));
}


generateCaptcha()
{
  this.subscriptions.push(this.loginSrv.GetCaptcha().subscribe(response => 
    {
      this.captcha = response;
      this.setCaptchaImage();
    },  
    error => throwError(error)));
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're keeping references to your subscriptions? I'm assuming you're keeping them to unsubscribe on destroy?

Comment: Correct - this is the reason - I'm doing that in the ngOnDestroy() event

Answer (score 2):

I personally have nothing against multiple `.subscribe` if your RXJS calls are not really supposed to be chained. However, if you are supposed to make 2 calls, yes, you should `concatMap` together.

Another thing that would clean up your code is the knowledge if the stream actually completes or not. This is a flaw in RXJS in my opinion, not knowing if the call you make is a 1 time thing, or if it's actually a stream.

If you make one http request and do not expect to keep the stream opened, then you do not have to keep a subscription to any of your RXJS calls. However, if you plan to keep a stream opened, I would recommend the `ngOnDestroy` technique.
You can read more about it ["Don't forget to unsubscribe"](https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) and maybe you should have a look at the same concept but telling you the opposite: ["Don't Unsubscribe"](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) :)

Also, you should read a bit more about your `throwError`. These should technically bubble up. The best way to actually learn is to code it yourself, I would recommend you go create a cold observable called login$() which does everything you are supposed to do. Only calling .subscribe() on it would return a **completed** observable.

Since other people have already commented on how to code, I won't code it here, but you should give it a shot!

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I do use the ngOnDestroy technique (not mentioned it in the code) to unsubscribe.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
this.login$ = this.loginServ.Login(userName, password).pipe(
  map(result => result.userData),
);

this.login$.pipe(
  filter(login => !login),
  tap(() => this.sessionService.increaseLoginAttempts()), // void method
);

this.login$.pipe(
  filter(Boolean),
  tap(() => this.sessionService.resetLoginAttempts()), // void method
  tap(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('')),
);

this.captcha$ = this.sessionService.loginAttempts$.pipe( // observable value
  filter(loginAttempts => loginAttempts >= 3),
  switchMap(() => this.loginServ.GetCaptcha()),
  // maybe setCaptchaImage() here since no idea what it does. maybe you can use async pipe for it?
);
```